# Showing a function is not an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

From Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right, 6.A 1,

Show that the function that takes $((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \times\mathbb{R}^2$ to $|x_1 y_1|+|x_2 y_2|$ is not an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^2$.
My attempt:

I will verify all the properties of inner products:

**Positivity**
$|x_1 x_1|+|x_2 x_2|$ is always $\geq0$ so this holds.

**Definiteness**
$\langle (x_1,x_2),(x_1,x_2)\rangle=|x_1 x_1|+|x_2 x_2|=0$ only if $|x_1 x_1|=|x_2 x_2|=0$ so $(x_1,x_2)=0$

**Additivity in first slot**
$\langle (x_1,x_2)+(z_1,z_2),(x_1,x_2)\rangle =\langle (x_1+z_1,x_2+z_2),(x_1,x_2)\rangle=|(x_1+z_1) y_1|+|(x_2+z_2)y_2|=|x_1 y_1|+|z_1 y_1|+|x_2 y_2|+|z_2 y_2|=\langle (x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)\rangle +\langle (z_1,z_2),(y_1,y_2)\rangle$

**Homogeneity in first slot**
$\langle \lambda (x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)\rangle=\langle (\lambda x_1,\lambda x_2),(y_1,y_2)\rangle =|\lambda x_1 y_1|+|\lambda x_2 y_2|=\lambda|x_1 y_1|+\lambda|x_2 y_2|=\lambda(|x_1 y_1|+|x_2 y_2|)=\lambda\langle (x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)\rangle$

**Conjugate symmetry**
$\overline {\langle (y_1,y_2),(x_1,x_2)\rangle}=\overline {|y_1 x_1|+|y_2 x_2|}=\overline{|y_1 x_1|}+\overline{|y_2 x_2|}=|y_1 x_1|+|y_2 x_2|=|x_1 y_1|+|x_2 y_2|$

It seems to me that everything holds so I am not sure why this is not an inner product.

Comment: $|\lambda x_1 y_1|+|\lambda x_2 y_2|=\lambda|x_1 y_1|+\lambda|x_2 y_2|$ is wrong.

Comment: Small typo: You probably meant $\geq 0$ in your positivity section?

Comment: $|(x_1+z_1) y_1|+|(x_2+z_2)y_2|=|x_1 y_1|+|z_1 y_1|+|x_2 y_2|+|z_2 y_2|$ is also wrong.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. Could you please explain why those are wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Put in some numbers, Nikolai, and see for yourself why they are wrong!

Comment: @Nikolai: Why do you think that those equalities hold?

Comment: Would you like to engage with the comments and/or the answer that have been posted, Nikolai?

Comment: Yes, thank you I have figured it out using the comments. I was not sure whether it was necessary to continue engaging in the comments since I am new here.

Comment: It's always polite to acknowledge people who have helped you, Nikolai. Also, as you have figured it out, you could write it up, and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT.** $|a+b|\neq |a|+|b|$, $|\lambda a|\neq \lambda |a|$. Consider negative numbers.